# How to use DLLs located on a shared drive?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

So the problem is we're using a set of components that update frequently. Instead of having to make sure that every development machine has the same version, it would be a whole lot easier to just have the used components in a central location on a shared drive, so that all the references could be pointed to them.

The problem is, though, that Visual Studio doesnt like this. If I add a reference pointing to the shared drive, I get the "Operation is not supported" -error, which, according to googling, is because of some security settings. I tried most things I found, ie. adding a `<loadFromRemoteSource enabled="true"/>` -tag to sgen.exe.config, my app.config and even the devenv.exe.config. I also made sure the dll is not blocked nor read-only. But the problem persists.

As soon as I simply copy the dll-file to a local drive and change the reference accordingly, everything works fine. But I'd much prefer just using it from a shared drive.

Oh and I should probably mention that I'm using VS2010 and .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the shared components in your source control repository (you do have one, right?).

In Visual Studio add them using relative paths, so when checking out your code, these components will already be in the right relative location.

When they need updating, simply update in source control too and get all the developers to get the latest version.

Comment: Yes I'm using a source control repository. What about if I need to use the same components on multiple different projects? It gets a bit tedious adding the dlls to every project, and then to make sure the dlls are same in every project. Or can I somehow make them all use the same?

Comment: @bobblez - You can have them in one repository and share that relative location across all projects. Some SCMs have facilities for things like that (externals in SVN, for example).